# TFS 2015 - WIT Field Validation - Date Validation

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I'm adding a custom field (date_x) of 'DateTime' type to a TFS Work Item.

I would like to add validation to prevent the input within this field from being backdated i.e. date_x must be greater or equal to today’s date.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how this could be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

TFS does not support date validation. But for tfs 2015 you may create a custom control (for web access and VS). Examples for custom controls you may find here:

[WitCustomControls](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=witcustomcontrols) (download archive)